# Atheros Wi-Fi doesn't work on ubuntu 17.10 for Acer Aspire

Tags: wireless, 17.10, acer, aspire, wifi-direct

After command

```
sudo lspci | grep Network
```

I got :

> 03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev31)

There is good news, when getting to wireless Internet, the Internet works for 3 seconds, and everything

dmesg | grep ath : `[   15.728351] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi oper_irq_mode 2 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   17.203121] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[   17.203124] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[   17.203803] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[   17.311405] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
[   17.792926] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[   17.799704] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x69
[   17.799705] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   17.799707] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   17.799707] ath: Regpair used: 0x69
[   18.417455] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   43.622615] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[   43.622621] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[   43.622624] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  110.998656] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  110.999122] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  115.692965] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  115.692971] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  115.692976] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  146.412246] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  146.412789] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.120259] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.120657] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.223030] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.223061] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.325403] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.325433] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.427722] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.427753] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.530021] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  151.530075] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.237895] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.238297] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.340260] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.340650] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.442552] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.442967] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.544962] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.545327] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.647677] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.647706] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.749978] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.750141] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.851988] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  156.852388] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  161.797292] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  161.797295] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  161.797297] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  215.741097] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  215.741101] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  215.741104] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  378.857011] ath10k_warn: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  378.857015] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  378.857468] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  401.268162] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  401.268167] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  401.268171] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  513.874327] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[  518.517802] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  518.517807] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  518.517809] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2626.082587] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 2639.549723] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 2639.549725] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 2639.549725] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3082.058439] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3082.058440] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3082.058441] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3086.904567] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3086.904573] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3086.904576] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3188.174361] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3188.174366] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3188.174368] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3222.883823] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3222.883827] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3222.883830] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3264.781291] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 3268.875564] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 3268.876039] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 3273.529102] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3273.529106] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3273.529108] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3613.002749] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3613.002754] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3613.002757] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3887.981946] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3887.981951] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3887.981955] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3991.242085] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 3991.242089] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 3991.242092] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 7682.051336] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: no channel configured; ignoring frame(s)!
[ 7686.691780] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[ 7686.691784] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[ 7686.691787] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP`

rfkill list all

`1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Comment: The driver `ath10k_pci` is already installed. If the wireless isn't working, then something else is wrong. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `dmesg | grep ath`.

Comment: @chili555 `rfkill list all` gave : no blocked all .

Comment: There is good news, when getting to wireless Internet, the Internet works for 3 seconds, and everything

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

> wlp3s0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Any improvement?

**EDIT**: I cannot, in good conscience, suggest that anyone protect their wireless only with WEP as it is quite insecure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy

> In August 2001, Scott Fluhrer, Itsik Mantin, and Adi Shamir published
>   a cryptanalysis of WEP that exploits the way the RC4 ciphers and IV
>   are used in WEP, resulting in a passive attack that can recover the
>   RC4 key after eavesdropping on the network. Depending on the amount of
>   network traffic, and thus the number of packets available for
>   inspection, a successful key recovery could take as little as one
>   minute.

I suggest that you disable power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Finally, let’s be certain that you have the latest firmware; from the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version
```

If your version is older than 1.169.2, then please do:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: HI.I Have B & G speeds only.Before change setting WEP 64 - Opeb, to WPA2-Personal-AES, ubuntu has stopped connecting to the Internet.

Comment: Ukraine is UA. Did you reboot both the router and the computer?

Comment: Did reboot all devices

Comment: I back to Wep 64, and wifi still worked!Thx!

Comment: Sorry, wireless 3 minutes worked and does not work again

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: By the way, I removed the encryption and it all worked, but you yourself understand that this is not the best solution to the problem

Comment: Senior!after the last manipulation the Internet stopped working even without encryption, how to return to the original settings?

Comment: Before wget conmmand i have this `error: unknown name or service`, before command sudo dpkg - `error: cannot access archive 'linux*.deb'` , version i have 1.169.2 . Life is sad ((((((((((((